# R: Adding values every n iteration

Tags: r

I have this very simple code:

```
for(n in 1:2){
  value=0
  for(i in 1:3){
    value[[i]]=runif(1, 5.0, 20)
  }
  cv=value
}
```

at every inner for loop iteration, I will get 3 random values e.g. `7.87 5.06 12.17` I want to put these values into `cv=7.87 5.06 12.17`.

Then I iterate again and I get 3 other different values e.g. `16.86 7.22 18.99` and I want to add them into `cv` and it will be `cv=7.87 5.06 12.17 16.86 7.22 18.99`. So the next values should be added from the 4th iteration in this case, and not overwritten. 
My aim is to iterate more than 2 times. So I want to add after every 3 iterations, `value`(with length 3) into `cv`.

Is there any type of list or vector that I could use for that?

Comment: `cv = c(cv, value)` ... but there is probably a way to do this without even using loops.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks a lot, no I need it with a loop, this is just a mini version of my actual code.

Comment: is there any reason not to do `cv = runif(6, 5, 20)`?

Comment: @MelissaKey yes there is, this is just a mini code of my actual code which computes something and stores into a value. Those values are then not random etc.

Comment: more generally, if you know how big `cv` is going to be, you want to create it at that length (`cv = rep(NA, total_length)`) and then replace those values.  Otherwise, `cv` will have to be copied every time you get to that part of your for loop - and that is slow.

Answer (score 0):

First, create an empty numeric vector:

```
v <- numeric()
```

Then, add your loop that iterates and add values to the numeric. The nice thing here is that you do not have to specify the length of `v` vector.

```
for (i in 1:2){
    for(j in 1:3){
        v <- c(v, runif(1, 5, 20))
    }
}
```